# can't get an expect console output when using async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, try-catch

```
    function fails4() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          reject(new Error());
        }, 100);
      });
    }

    async function myFunc4() {
      try {
        await fails4();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log('that failed', e); //<-- this gets called
      }
    }
    async function loadmYScript() {
      try {
        await myFunc4();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(123);
      }
    }
    loadmYScript();
```

> cant't execute the console.log(123) as I expected can anybody help me with this question very appreciated

Comment: Why is that unexpected? `myFunc4` catches the error, so `loadmYScript` doesn't see one.

Comment: If you want loadmYScript to handle the error, either don't catch it in myFunc4, or re-throw the error in myFunc4's catch block. `console.log('that failed', e); throw e;`

Answer (score 1):

You're calling loadmYScript, which in turn calls myFunc4, which in turn calls fails4. This last one (fails4) throws an error. The error is "catch-ed" by myFunc4. Inside this catch block you don't throw any error, there's only a couple of logs, so the result of loadmYScript is a fulfilled promise with undefined value. It is not rejected because myFunc4 doesn't throw the error.

If you throw an error inside the catch block of myFunc4, you will have your 123 logged, and the promise will be rejected.